# Need to convert an LEFT JOIN to JPQL

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpql, outer-join, migrate

immagine following problem:
somebody wants to buy a basket of fruit containing green fruits from Africa and South America but no red fruits from Africa.

for that we think about following classes:

```
    class Basket
    {
      int id;
      Collection<Fruit> fruits; 
    }

    class Fruit
    {
      int id;
      int basketId;
      String origin
      Color color;
    }
```

the mapping will be MxM.
It is intended that Fruit has no Basket object, but if necessary i could implement it.

for Native SQL i would use:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
      Basket b 
    JOIN 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT basketId 
      FROM Fruit 
      WHERE color='green' AND (origin='Africa' OR origin='South America')
    ) f1 ON (b.id=f1.basketId) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT basketId 
      FROM Fruit 
      WHERE color='red' AND (origin='Africa')
    ) f2 ON (b.id=f2.basketId) 
    WHERE f2.basketId IS NULL
```

What will be the Query in JPQL?

i tried already following:

```
    SELECT b 
    FROM Basket b 
    WHERE 
      b.id IN (
        SELECT f1.basketId FROM Fruit f1 
        WHERE f1.color='green' AND (f1.origin='Africa' OR f1.origin='South America')
      ) AND
      b.id NOT IN (
        SELECT f2.basketId FROM Fruit f2 
        WHERE f2.color='red' AND (origin='Africa'))
```

but this query took 12000ms instead of 50 ms.
(This is just a simple example. The real Tables have around 750000 "fruits" and 10000 "baskets" with much more fields each.)

Thanks in advance

Gerald

Comment: what i found out so far:
benchmarks avg Querytime (10000 queries):
a) Standard SQL (Left Join)  vs b) JPQL (exists):

MySQL: a=60s vs b=1050s;
PostgreSQL: a=144s vs b=62s;
H2: a=77s vs b=1817s

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
select b from Basket b where
    exists (select f.id from Fruit f where f.basket = b and f.color = 'green')
    and not exists (select f.id from Fruit f where f.basket = b and f.color = 'red')
```

But I'm not sure it would be faster. It depends on the execution plan, which depends on the database indexes. There should be an index on `Fruit.basketId` and on `Fruit.color`.

Comment: the subselect is already well indexed from the earlier query. I added the index to "basketId", but it still takes ages... :-/ i think EXISTS works similar like IN.

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
select b from Basket b join b.fruits f where f.color = 'green' and not f.color = 'red';
```

The join is probably optional so it could also be

```
select b from Basket b where b.fruits.color = 'green' and not b.fruits.color = 'red';
```

Comment: hmmm I think I need to extend this example... thik about there is an additional field "String origin" in the fruits class and you want green fruits from africa and southamerica, and no red fruits from africa.